# Calculate percentage from datagridview data with linq query

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview

I use this linq query to group and calculate some values from datagridview.

```
var Sums = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
          .Where(row => row.Cells[8].Value != null)
        .GroupBy(row => row.Cells[8].Value.ToString()) 

        .Select(g => new { Gruppo = g.Key, Serie = g.Sum(row => Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[2].Value)) });
```

[image: Here the result]

How can I improve this adding the percentage calculation between each group and the total?

What I want is that if the total of "Serie" column values is 20 (for example), in a third column I see that 3 (the value in the first cell) is the 15% etc.

Comment: for DataSource I used: dataGridView.DataSource = Sums.ToList(); the problem is that with any code I use to calculate the percentage, I get 0 as result

Comment: @JohnG I found the problem. I changed the linq query from Convert.ToInt to Convert.ToDecimal and I get the correct result, then I used dataGridView1.Columns["Percent"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "0.00'%'"; from your answer to formate the result. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
Sums = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
        .Where(row => row.Cells[8].Value != null)
        .GroupBy(row => row.Cells[8].Value.ToString()) 
        .Select(g => new 
            { 
                Gruppo = g.Key,
                Serie = g.Sum(row => Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[2].Value)),
                Percente = (g.Sum(row => Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[2].Value)) / Convert.ToInt32(label15.Text)) * 100
            });
```

Comment: This is giving me the same result. What I'm trying to do is to have a third column with the % between values

Comment: @Gabriele You want to know, for example, what percent 'glutei' is out of all of the groups and include that with the result?

Comment: yes, so in the example up, if the total of values is 20, glutei is 15% because as value 3

Comment: I don't you can do that in one LINQ line because you would have to get the total value.  You wouldn't know that until it's done.   Maybe you could but it would look dirty

Comment: I have the total value in a label, so I can get from: Convert.ToInt32(label15.Text). Now that I have the total, how I can do that?

Comment: I'm sorry but it returns 0 in every row as percentage